# How can I make "${a}" as a argument of "String[] args" in main method java?

Tags: java, arguments, program-entry-point

When I set arguments as `${a}` in eclipse, it tell me:

> Reference to underfined variable a

But I just make `${a}` as a argument.

Comment: Can you show how you set arguments as "${a}" in eclipse ?

Comment: Can you try to escape the dollar sign? i.e. `\$`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ this can be done in the "run as" dialog, run as--->run configurations--->arguments

Comment: @Aaron i already tried it that and unuseful

Comment: @zapl perfect! thank you very much!